# lighthouse report; insecure requests found

Tags: google-chrome, https, lighthouse

when I to test my Website (it is outside from my computer) with the tool lighthouse on Chrome, comes this report;

> All sites should be protected with HTTPS, even ones that don't handle sensitive data. HTTPS prevents intruders from tampering with or passively listening in on the communications between your app and your users and is a prerequisite for HTTP/2 and many new web platform APIs. Learn more.

What I don't Understand why to come this, I have my Website with **https** — the report to say that my images and URL do not use HTTPS.
Screenshot from this warning;

[image]

I have to test my Website for https mistake with https://www.whynopadlock.com/f73e9366-da69-4ebf-a73f-6ceff2161cd6

Screenshot from it,

[image]

How to see, I have all gut, but the Tool **lighthouse** every time give me a similar result...

Can Please anyone help me with this problem, Thanks!

Comment: is the problem is solved or still having the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the transfer protocol your site current uses is HTTP/1.1
 which has been the de-facto standard since 1997. In an effort to ensure a secure encrypted connection between browsers and websites, giants like [Google](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-sets-https-deadline/236225/) and [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/) have been pushing sites to use HTTPS.

Google came up with a new way networking protocol [SPDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) which is termed a precursor to HTTP/2 which rolled out in 2015. Google suggests websites to use HTTP/2 as the new de-facto standard protocol which brings in multiplexing, header compression, binary transfer of data and [much more](https://searchengineland.com/everyone-moving-http2-236716).

The message that you have recieved would go away once you enable HTTP/2 on your server

As you haven't mentioned your webserver, here's how you enable it for [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-9-http2-server-push/) and [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html)

Comment: Very thanks for your answer!, how can implement it on my Webserver, it is outside of my computer...

Comment: Could you give me a little specs about your setup? From your URL, I can see that your site is hosted on Linode. Could you tell what kind of stack you use?

Comment: I am new with server..., can please to say with easy words what you will from me